# Why I cannot put the subclass into hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, subclass, extends

As mentioned in title, I have created few subclasses for basicHpPotion class under item and potion classes. I would like put it into hashmap but the system(red line underneath) do not let me do that. What's the problem? Shop.java is the main script to have a hashmap.

Item.java

```
package com.mainsystem;

public class Item {
    String name;
    String type;

    public Item() {};

    public Item(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Potion.java

```
package com.mainsystem;

public class Potion extends Item {
    int hpRecoverValue;

    public Potion() {
    };
    public Potion(String name, String type, int hpRecoverValue) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.hpRecoverValue = hpRecoverValue;
    }
}
```

BasicHpPotion.java

```
package com.mainsystem;

public class BasicHPPotion extends Potion {
    String name = "Basic HP Potion";
    String type = "Potion";
    int hpRecoverValue = 100;

    BasicHPPotion() {
    };
}
```

Shop.java

```
package com.mainsystem;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Shop {
    HashMap<Item, Integer> slot = new HashMap<>();
    Item basicHpPotion = new BasicHPPotion();
    slot.put(basicHpPotion,5);
}
```

I did try a different class to fit in but it still did not work.  I expect the item basicHpPotion can be fitted into the hashmap. :(

Comment: in line Item basicHpPotion = new BasicHPPotion(); no data because you dont set data of properities

Comment: *"I would like fit it into hashmap but i wouldn't let me do that."* - What do you mean by that?  Show us the code and the error messages.

Comment: Yea ... I spotted a number of errors and mistakes.  Another mistake is that since you don't override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods, hashmap keys will have identity semantics; e.g. all `Item` instances will be different as keys.

Comment: how to set properities..? I am not know how actual way to do. Any example can show me? Many Thanks:)

Comment: those error messages said syntax error"Identifier" to complete MethodHeaderName and "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName

Comment: Complete error message please ... and the precise code that triggered them.  They sound like simple Java compilation errors, not something to do with putting things into hashmaps.   But we need more information.

Comment: You cannot simple write statements into classes - statements like `slot.put(basicHpPotion,5);` are only allowed within code blocks (methods, constructors and (static) initializer blocks).

Comment: Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
Syntax error on token ",", / expected
Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration